# Laravel 8 reset password doesn't send emails

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

I know this issue has been brought up several times but I couldn't find any solution for my problem.
Here's the MAIL part of my .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=john.doe@domainename.fr
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

In my code the emails are sent by using the Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail class and everything works fine.

Now when it comes to the reset password, everything seems ok except that no email is received.
I have no error in the var/log/mail.log file where it says: `mail accepted for delivery`
I've traced the code all the way through to the SwiftMailer send() function but I haven't found out where this problem comes from.

Can someone helps me ?

Comment: this will try to use a smtp server on the server itself to send mail. Have you configured SMPT or something like `sendmail` for sending mail on your server?

Comment: @MaartenDev Yes I did, as I said, the emails sent with my code are properly sent and received.

Answer (score 0):

In the localhost project use that config in the .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER='smtp'
MAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME='email@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD='password'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS='email@gmail.com'
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

In the server use:

```
MAIL_MAILER='sendmail'
MAIL_HOST='sendmail.googlemail.com'
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME='email@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD="password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION='tls'
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS='email@gmail.com'
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score -2):

It will not work with Mail_Host=localhost .
Please try gmail smtp server using these configuration.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ENTER_YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS
MAIL_PASSWORD=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

also please on this "Less secure app access" option in your gmail account.